# Bochner formula in different forms

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, dirac-operator

I am looking for a reference (better a book) that contain integral Bochner formulas for domains with boundary (I need it for 1-forms and functions only).

For example I will need the following formula:
$$\int\limits_\Omega |\Delta f|^2
-|\mathrm{Hess}f|^2
+\langle\mathrm{Ric}(\nabla f),\nabla f\rangle
=\int\limits_{\partial\Omega}
H\cdot|\nabla f|^2,$$
where $H$ denotes mean curvature of $\partial \Omega$ and $f$ vanish on the boundary, but I will also need its analog for 1-forms and yet general boundary condition.

So far I found "Spin geometry" by Lawson and Michelsohn --- based on II/§5, it is easy to derive any formula I need (but I am sure someone did it somewhere).

Comment: What is a *relative* Bochner formula? IIRC, Wu's "The Bochner Technique in Differential Geometry" (https://bookstore.ams.org/ctm-6/) states the Bochner-Weitzenböck formulas for 1-forms and functions as corollaries.

Comment: @M.G. I mean for domains with boundary.

Comment: @M.G. No, I did not find it in this book.

Comment: Anton, it appears you are having something different in mind than what I thought initially, apologies. I was thinking of the following (stated on p.307 in Wu's book more or less): if $\psi$ is a harmonic 1-form, then $-\Delta||\psi||^2 = 2\sum_{k=1}^n||\nabla_{X_k}\psi||^2 + 2\operatorname{Ric}(\psi^\#,\psi^\#)$, where $\{X_k:1\leq k\leq n\}$ is a frame field (sorry, notations are from my own notes, so slightly different than in Wu's book). Weird, I was sure there was an explicit statement for harmonic 0-forms, but now I see there is not (but it follows from WFII).

Comment: Did you check Riemannian Geometry by Petersen? If I correctly remember he discusses the Bochner and the Bochner-Weitzenböck formulas quite extensively.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz yes I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a reference to a paper; Theorem 3 gives a general formula for differential forms with no constraints on the boundary values.  I'm not sure if this shows up in a book yet.

**Raulot, S.; Savo, A**. A Reilly formula and eigenvalue estimates for differential forms. *J. Geom. Anal*. **21** (2011), no. 3, 620--640. [MR2810846](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2810846).

[Here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2Fs12220-010-9161-0) is a direct link to the article.

Comment: I fixed the MR link.  Are you looking for a slightly different version of the Reilly formula than that presented in this reference?

Comment: It seems to be all I need, except the notations are different from those I used to. Also, I feel more comfortable to refer to a book; say by now I would better use "Spin Geometry" of Lawson and Michelsohn.